# SQL: Merge two selects to one query

Tags: php, sql, join, merge, union

I want to merge two selects to make one query for use in PHP.
Each user reports time, this time is either normal time (overtime = 0) or overtime (overtime = 1).

```
SELECT username, 
       userlastname,
       SUM(time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5 + time6),
       userid,
       overtime 
FROM users, time 
WHERE timeyear = $y
      AND timeproid = $proid 
      AND userid = timeuserid
      AND timeweek = $week 
GROUP BY userlastname, username, userid, overtime
```

I have a table displayed that has two rows for each user, one for overtime time and one for normal time. I select overtime because I do if overtime = 0 show overtime time as 0 else show overtime as SUM(time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5 + time6)

Is there any way I can merge the two? Try this [link](http://s7.postimage.org/sljxioqfv/Screen_Shot_2012_07_19_at_16_27_52.png): Its how it looks now. I would like the 6 and 5.5 combined to make 11.5 and the 5.5 (overtime) to be left as 5.5

[See this](http://s7.postimage.org/sljxioqfv/Screen_Shot_2012_07_19_at_16_27_52.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT username,
       userlastname,
       SUM(CASE WHEN overtime = 0 THEN
              time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5 + time6
           ELSE 0 END) AS normaltime,
       userid,
       SUM(overtime) AS overtime
FROM users, time 
WHERE timeyear = $y
  AND timeproid = $proid 
  AND userid = timeuserid
  AND timeweek = $week 
GROUP BY userlastname, username, userid;
```

This should give you the sum of "overtimes" into overtime, and the sum of other times as "normaltime". If I understand correctly, you record overtime time into the overtime column, and no-overtime time elsewhere.

If, instead, you use overtime as a "flag" that means "time0 is now overtime", then you need to write it like this:

```
SELECT username,
       userlastname,
       SUM(CASE WHEN overtime = 0 THEN
              time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5 + time6
           ELSE 0 END) AS normaltime,
       userid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN overtime != 0 THEN
              time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5 + time6
           ELSE 0 END) AS overtime,
FROM users, time 
WHERE timeyear = $y
  AND timeproid = $proid 
  AND userid = timeuserid
  AND timeweek = $week 
GROUP BY userlastname, username, userid;
```

Comment: What I have is time0...time6 and an overtime column set to 0 or 1 to say if time0...6 is normal time or overtime. I updated the question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional statements within a query using the CASE WHEN/THEN END syntax.

```
SELECT u.username, u.userlastname, CASE WHEN t.overtime = 1 THEN SUM(t.time0 + t.time1 + t.time2 + t.time3 + t.time4 + t.time5 + t.time6) ELSE 0 END as overtime, u.userid
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN time t ON(u.userid=t.timeuserid)
WHERE t.timeyear = $y AND t.timeproid = $proid AND t.timeweek = $week 
GROUP BY u.userlastname, u.username, u.userid, t.overtime
```

Comment: Please see the updated question and the link I added, because it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise does a union meet your needs (certainly not the best performance oriented answer)?

```
SELECT username, 
       userlastname,
       SUM(time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5 + time6) as overtime,
       userid,
       overtime 
FROM users, time 
WHERE timeyear = $y
      AND timeproid = $proid 
      AND userid = timeuserid
      AND timeweek = $week 
      AND overtime=1
GROUP BY userlastname, username, userid
union
SELECT username, 
       userlastname,
       0 as overtime,
       userid,
       overtime 
FROM users, time 
WHERE timeyear = $y
      AND timeproid = $proid 
      AND userid = timeuserid
      AND timeweek = $week
      AND overtime=0 
GROUP BY userlastname, username, userid
```